# Angular 6 HttpInterceptor correct behaviour

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-http-interceptors

I have written an `Http Interceptor` in `Angular 6 .` 
The goal is to reload the home page when `302 status` is returned. 
I am currently not able to understand why the `HttpInterceptor` is behaving the way it is

**Code  :**

API call which returns `302 status` is below. 
`this._service.checkStatus()` calls back end API which returns `302 http status`

**API Code :**

```
public checkStatus() : void  {


      this._service.checkStatus().subscribe(

        (data) => console.log('success In checkStatus '),
        (error)=>console.log('error In checkStatus')
      );

 }
```

**Interceptor Code  :**

```
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{


    constructor(){

    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        console.log('inside interceptor' );
        return next.handle(request).pipe(

        tap(
                event =>{
                },
                error=>{
                    console.log(error);

                    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                        if (error.status === 302) {
                            window.location.reload();                      
                        }
                      }
                }
            )
       );

    }

}
```

**Issue :**

Now the issue is when `302 status` is returned , the line `(error)=>console.log('error In checkStatus')` still gets executed in API - `checkStatus` call.

My question is ,why error handler in API call still gets called . 
That is , after 302 is returned , the page gets reloaded with `window.location.reload()`

But the error handler `(error)=>console.log('error In checkStatus')` still gets invoked.

What needs to be done to prevent execution of Error handler code inside `checkStatus` API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with catchError.

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(   

     tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
       console.log('tap', event);
     }),

     catchError(error => {

       console.log('catchError', error);

       if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
         if (error.status === 302) {
           window.location.reload();                      
         }
       }

       return throwError(error);     
     })
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Michael . That was the issue